# Correct way of calling fork() after parent has created threads?

Tags: multithreading, fork, posix

I'm implementing a complex application that takes third-party plug-ins, and I want to run the plug-in code in child processes for isolation.  The parent process needs to be multithreaded, but I have read that [`fork` may be unsafe in multithreaded processes](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them), particularly if you do not immediately call `execve`, and that [`pthread_atfork` is not a complete solution](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13502).

What do other complex applications do about this?  I know Chrome uses both subprocesses and multithreading simultaneously, so it must be *possible*.

Comment: Are you aware of `select()`/`poll()`? Are you using it?

Comment: @Olaf This question is more properly tagged POSIX and _neither_ C nor C++, I think.  It is about details of the way two OS features interact, that would apply to any programming language built on the same primitives.

Comment: @zwol Maybe. I think it is unclear what OP **specifically** asks.

Comment: @Olaf I'm just starting out with this stuff and I'm primarily using C++. But fork() and dlopen() are system calls which is why I added the C tag,

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I am not aware of select() and poll(). I'll check those out. Thanks!

Comment: @Olaf: I disagree, it is crystal clear as-is.  Perhaps you are unfamiliar with the problem OP is talking about, but if you've ever tripped over it - which anyone qualified to answer the question has - it requires no further explanation.

Comment: @zwol: You completely changed the question with your edit! That's beyond what edits are meant for. Please roll back.

Comment: @user2624119: You should not add tags, just because you use functions **with a C ABI**. A library has no source code. It just follows an ABI. Could very well be written in Fortran or Assembly as well.

Comment: @Olaf I did not change the question.  If it looks like the question is now different, that just demonstrates that you didn't understand what the question was.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `fork()` in a multithreaded program is well-defined.  On success, the child process has exactly one thread -- the same one that called `fork()` in the parent program.  Although this *can* be a problem, whether it actually *is* a problem depends on the circumstances.

***When is `fork()`ing a problem for a multithreaded program?***

The main reason for `fork()`ing to present a problem in a multithreaded program is that the child process depends on mutexes, condition variables, etc. that other threads can no longer be relied upon to manipulate.  For example, if the child needs to acquire a process-private mutex that it does not already hold, then it may be that that mutex was held by a different thread at the time of the fork.  In that case, it will never be released in the child process, because no thread that could release it exists in the child.

***When is `fork()`ing*** **not** ***a problem for a multithreaded program?***

One of the common idioms involving `fork()` is to immediately follow it up by execing another program.  That's no problem, regardless of the threadedness of the parent.

Alternatively, if the child process does not depend on any problematic resources, then nothing special need be done.  Note that *process-shared* interthread objects are not "problematic" in this sense.  This situation is fairly common, and it sounds like it might be your case.

Otherwise, it's not a problem if the parent's forking thread can and does acquire all the process-private interthread resources that the child will need before it forks.  Handlers registered by `pthread_atfork()` can help with this under some circumstances, but under others, it makes more sense for that to be done in the immediate environs of the fork call.

***Overall***

You've presented the question as if `fork()`ing was a deep and troublesome problem for multithreaded programs.  It is certainly a problem that should be considered, and it is typically best to avoid using both multiple threads and multiple processes.  Therefore, inasmuch as you want multiple processes so as to have separate address spaces and perhaps name spaces into which to load plugins, perhaps you should consider using separate processes wherever you now use threads.  On the other hand, if you exercise some thought and care, you can probably make it work just fine for your multi-threaded process to fork children and interact with them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! The "dine in the immediate environs of the fork() call" is pretty much what I did to stop the program from crashing. A c++ std::thread in the parent created before fork was being cloned in the child and the "dead" thread object in the child was going out of scope without join being called on it. This led to a c++ exception that said "Terminated without active exception". It appears I have some research to do ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot ensure that `fork` is only used under safe circumstances, as described in [John Bollinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679479/388520), a general workaround is to use a "fork server".  Before creating any threads, the original process forks once.  The child process is the fork server; it remains single-threaded.  The parent process now goes ahead and creates its threads.  Whenever the parent would want to call `fork`, it instead sends a message to the fork server asking it to do so.

If the (ultimate) child processes also need to communicate with the parent, the easiest way to accomplish this is to have the parent create pipes for each child's stdin and stdout, and then transfer the child sides of those pipes to the fork server, using a [`SCM_RIGHTS` special message](https://ptspts.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-send-unix-file-descriptors.html).  You can send file descriptors and data simultaneously.  The communication protocol between the fork server and the parent might need to get pretty fancy — look at the `posix_spawn` API for a more-or-less complete list of all the knobs you might want.  (Note: `posix_spawn` is just a library wrapper around `fork`; using it will **not** avoid the original problem.)

The fork server is also responsible for calling `waitpid` and relaying exit statuses back to the parent.  This is trickier than it ought to be, because the standard APIs for waiting for the next of several possible events (`select` and `poll`) do not accept a process ID as one of the things to wait for.  (BSD's `kqueue` *does*, but you're probably not on a BSD.)  You have to do a messy dance with `SIGCHLD` and a pipe-to-self instead.

Comment: That seeks like an interesting solution.
Will this new "fork server" also be responsible for passing any information coming from the children to the "original parent"? How will the final children communicate with the original parent without falling back on sockets... or perhaps named pipes? This is getting quite unwieldy :)

Comment: @user2624119 I'll add something about that to the answer.